# How to Disable/Enable location in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I want to enable/disable the user location by tapping on a button.

in my AppDelegate I have this :

```
    let core = CLLocationManager()

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            core.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
             ...
```

In my OptionController I have this :

```
 @IBAction func disablePermissionLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
```

But I have no idea how I can enable location if the user have disabled it in the very first launching of the app or disable location if the user have enabled it in the very first launching of the app.

Answer (score 9):

if you have two buttons than do like this:-
add delegate - CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
//global varible :
var  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
func viewdidLoad(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
  }
func enableLocationManager() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func disableLocationManager() {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: TIP : in order to use startUpdatingLocation() you must enable the location update background mode in project capability

WORD OF CAUTION : using startUpdatingLocation() will result in real time location updates and apple considers it very seriously, using background mode for any other purpose then location update will result in app rejection :)

Comment: I din ask the question to accept the answer buddy :) Asking wrong person :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chaudhary but i want to disable the location authorization not the update of the tracking mode in the map.

Comment: are you talking about to disable location  authorization alert which ask user to allow app to access loaction service or some other thing

Comment: for exemple : the first time you launch the app the alert which ask user to allow access location appear and you accept.
and one day later you want to disable this by tapping on the button what is the command that allow this ?

Comment: you did not do it programatically . you have option to go in application setting and off the location service from there.